# Elasticsearch: How to query through user's follow data without efficiently (e.g. maybe no parent/child)?

Tags: elasticsearch

tl;dr: I need to search for users who follow user 123, where their username would match "foo", in an environment where usernames can be changed, and cannot find an efficient manner to do so.

I have users who can follow each other, and I need to be able to search through my users' followers and who they're following by username.  We already use elasticsearch for usernames, so this seemed to be a logical solution.  Given that users can change their usernames on the fly, however, this presents a lot of issues.  Below are strategies that have been ruled out:

1. Create an entry in elasticsearch representing the follow, including the username of the following and followed user in the row

1A. Do this with subdocuments, where the subdocuments would be entries in our existing user search

We have one particular user who is followed by 65k people, and is following 265k himself.  If we were to use subdocuments, and this user one day decided to change his username, this would require the reindexing of >300k documents, so this would be extremely expensive in any such case.

2. Use parent/child relationships

This feels like the most tempting solution as it doesn't require any extensive re-indexing, but it would require a join between the user search and follow indexes, each of which are extremely large.  It feels like a slowdown is inevitable with this solution.

3. Include an array/object of a user's followers/followings in each row of the user search.  So user X would have {"followers": [1,2,10], "following": [2, 5, 15]}.  When searching among user X's followers, you search for any user with a particular username where their "following" array/object contains X's id.

I'm unsure if this is performant.  Would the elements of the array be searched by hash?

To our understanding, to maintain these lists, we would need to add/delete from this array on the fly, and to remove from the list we need to run a script, which may not be possible in AWS.  If we were to go this approach, we would need an infrastructure change.

Comment: Sometimes 2 queries maybe better then one. But your Solution 3 seems not that bad and is the most efficent of them. But beware that "updating" always means deleting and reindexing a document. So if your documents are already huge and have nested stuff you may want this in an extra index which just has userid, following, followers. When space is not an issue redundancy may be key.

Comment: @DennisIch agreed on 2 queries sometimes being better than 1, but when trying that approach, the issue is simply that we may not receive a match even if we pull 10k username matches for a user with a small number of followers.

Comment: Is it not possible to simply append/remove from an array in elasticsearch without deleting and re-indexing the entire object?  I would assume an array of length 260k would be considered big?

Comment: I would not consider it big because it still is just one document with 260k words in it. If you have parent-child relations you index 260k documents for that case which is actually terrible. So lets talk about the actual usecase: what is a query you want to achieve? The Usecase from your post would be like "match username: xxx AND match follows: yyy". You actually can add to arrays but under the hood the document gets deleted and reindexed because lucenes documents are immutable.

Comment: Wouldn't parent-child not require re-indexing?  In that use-case, the user object (containing the username) would be the child, so only it would be reindexed.  Of course my issue there is the actual query would be slow.

Comment: My usecase would be that.  "Matches: 'dennis', follows: 'limasxgoesto0_user_id'".  Is removing from an array possible without scripting?  I suppose I could do it applicationside...

Comment: I know you can add something to an array easily. But its not possible to remove. Under the hood the document WILL get reindexed anyway. You may not see it but it will. But actually that should not be a problem. Its not like you reindex millions of documents at once. Even if the document is a megabyte of data it should be done in a second or less so don't worry and just try the array. If the performance is real bad consider something else but this is the straight forward approach that should work.

Comment: Sounds in line with what we were going to do.  We'll try and see if there's an efficient way to remove from the array (meaning not have to load it into our application's memory), but otherwise it sounds good to me

Comment: If you find a way to do so please update this with an answer to your own question I would be very interested in that.